# How to improve and fix simple python scoring algorithm

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get my scoring function to determine using the filled columns what the null value on the last column would be. This algorithm is based on a MySQL one shown below. I'm running into alot of syntax errors in relation to the text variables, as well as it seems very streched and not condensed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'BP systolic': [139, 125, 117], 
     'BP diastolic': [83, 76, 87], 
     'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Female'], 
     '1st degree relative with diabetes': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
     'Physically active': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
     'Age, years': [34, 48, 57],
     'history of hypertension': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
     'BMI, kg/m²': [40, 25, 17],
     'American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)    
points = []
for i in range(0, len(df['BP systolic'])):
    p = 0
    
    r1 = df['BP systolic'][i]
    r2 = df['BP diastolic'][i]
    r3 = df['Gender'][i]
    r4 = df['1st degree relative with diabetes'][i]
    r5 = df['Physically active'][i]
    r6 = df['Age, years'][i]
    r7 = df['history of hypertension'][i]
    r8 = df['BMI, kg/m²'][i]

    if r1 > 140:
        p += 1
        points.append([r1, p])
    else:
        p += 0
        points.append([r1, p])
        
    if r2 > 90:
        p += 1
        points.append([r2, p])
    else:
        p += 0
        points.append([r2, p])
        
    if r3 = 'Male':
        p += 1
        points.append([r3, p])
    else:
        p += 0
        points.append([r3, p])
     
    if r4 = 'Yes':
        p += 1
        points.append([r4, p])
    else:
        p += 0
        points.append([r4, p])
        
    if r5 = 'No':
        p += 1
        points.append([r5, p])
    else:
        p += 0
        points.append([r5, p])
        
    if r6 < 40:
        p += 0
        points.append([r6, p])
    elif r6 > 40 < 50:
        p += 1
        points.append([r6, p])
    elif r6 > 50 < 60:
        p += 2
        points.append([r6, p])
    else:
        p += 3
        points.append([r6, p])
        
    if r7 = 'Yes':
        p += 1
        points.append([r7, p])
    else:
        p += 0
        points.append([r7, p])
        
    if r8 < 25:
        p += 0
        points.append([r8, p])
    elif r8 > 25 < 30:
        p += 1
        points.append([r8, p])
    elif r8 > 30 < 40:
        p += 2
        points.append([r8, p])
    else:
        p += 3
        points.append([r8, p])
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
print(df)
print(points)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `trial1`.`trial1` ( `Name` TEXT NULL , `Age, years` INT NULL , `Gender` TEXT NULL , `1st degree relative with diabetes` TEXT NULL , `history of hypertension` TEXT NULL , `BP systolic` INT NULL , `BP diastolic` INT NULL , `Physically active` TEXT NULL , `BMI, kg/m²` INT NULL , `American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator` FLOAT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `trial1` (`Name`, `Age, years`, `Gender`, `1st degree relative with diabetes`, `history of hypertension`, `BP systolic`, `BP diastolic`, `Physically active`, `BMI, kg/m²`, `American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator`) VALUES ('Person A', '34', 'Male', 'Yes', 'Yes', '139', '83', 'Yes', '40', NULL);
INSERT INTO `trial1` (`Name`, `Age, years`, `Gender`, `1st degree relative with diabetes`, `history of hypertension`, `BP systolic`, `BP diastolic`, `Physically active`, `BMI, kg/m²`, `American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator`) VALUES ('Person B', '48', 'Female', 'Yes', 'No', '125', '76', 'Yes', '25', NULL);
INSERT INTO `trial1` (`Name`, `Age, years`, `Gender`, `1st degree relative with diabetes`, `history of hypertension`, `BP systolic`, `BP diastolic`, `Physically active`, `BMI, kg/m²`, `American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator`) VALUES ('Person C', '57', 'Female', 'No', 'Yes', '117', '87', 'No', '17', NULL);
update trial1
set `American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator` = ( 
  (`BP systolic` >= 140) + (`BP diastolic` >= 90) +
  (`Gender` = 'Male') +
  (`1st degree relative with diabetes` = 'Yes') +
  (`history of hypertension` = 'Yes') +
  (`Physically active` = 'No') +
  case
    when `Age, years` < 40 then 0 
    when `Age, years` BETWEEN 40 AND 49 then 1 
    when `Age, years` BETWEEN 50 AND 59 then 2
    when `Age, years` >= 60 then 3
  end +  
  case
    when `BMI, kg/m²` < 25 then 0
    when `BMI, kg/m²` BETWEEN 25 AND 30 then 1 
    when `BMI, kg/m²` BETWEEN 31 AND 39 then 2 
    when `BMI, kg/m²` >= 40 then 3
  end
) / 12 
where `American Diabetes Association (ADA) Risk Calculator` is null
```

Comment: hi, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @IronMan File "<string>", line 43
    if r3 = ['Male']:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 2 equal signs. `if r3 == ['Male']`

Comment: yes, this resolved all the text variable syntax errors, in relation either to some variables not taking the assigned score or how i could actually asign the column to that sum p in this case, have you any idea?